# Find/Replace in MS word from text to auto fill box

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

Background: I am working towards the partial automation of in-house specification sheets for construction projects. Normally I need to update headers on 16/20 rocuments, owner on 6/20, dates on 8/20 and two sheets have entire sections that need to be updated with each project.

so far I have all 2p sheets combined into Word, and have drafted a project information sheet where all the variable information cam be edited.

so far I have the legacy text fill working, but instead of going through the entire document is there a way to find replace the current project title with a Referance Box? I remember something from word 2007 about being able to ctrl H enter Find and then in replace {REF [ref name]} but I can't figure out what I am missing. can anyone help? I put an example below of what I need to do

my entry field is as follows:
Project Title: [Sealand Desert Appreciation Building]

then needs to update headers and spots within documents
"The Sealand Desert Appreciation Society Building are a great investment "

so that when the project title is updated on Page 1 to:
Project Title: [Sealand Mountaineering Society Complex]

it will then update headers and Project tiles through out the document.
How do I do this as a Find Replace? I have 18 pieces of information to do this with

I have tried doing ctrl H and replace with {Ref [ref ID]} no luck, research on my own and videos